# Determine mobile operator name using IP Address

Tags: java, mobile

Do we have any API or service provider which will let us know the name of mobile carrier company using IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if any free solution exists, but there are paid ones like [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/isp).